# Trying to get property of non-object error with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I am starting to play with phpunit, and my exposure to OO PHP is limited, so I think I'm missing something fundamental.  When setting up a very simple test, I get the error `Trying to get property of non-object`.

This is what I'm trying to test

```
class Employee
{
    protected $jobTypeModifier, $manager, $id;
    public $name, $employee, $years, $allowances, $allowances_left, $extra, $carried, $totalTaken, $holidays;

    function Employee($id)
    {
        $this->jobTypeModifier = 1;
        $this->manager = 0;
        $this->totalTaken = 0;
        $this->setEmployeeId($id);
    }

    function myId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

And this is my test

```
class EmployeeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $employee;

    protected function setUp(){
        $this->employee = new Employee(1);
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
        unset($this->employee);
    }

    public function testMyId()
    {
        $actual = $this->employee->myId();
        $expected = 1;
        $this->assertEquals($actual, $expected);
    }
}
```

I assume I'm missing something fundamental / obvious here?

Comment: First of all from PHP 5.3.3 your "Employee" won't be treated as construct but just regular method. Use __construct as constructor. Check which version oh PHP do you have.

Comment: Ah, this is very old code and we are now on 5.3 I believe.  I'll change the Employee function to __construct and see if that solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

- first of all as I said in comment:

> First of all from PHP 5.3.3 your "Employee" won't be treated as
>   construct but just regular method. Use __construct as constructor.
>   Check which version oh PHP do you have.

- in your method `Employee` you call non-existing method `setEmployeeId`
- separate your properties line by line
- use public/protected/private when you define your methods
- In assertions the expected value should pass as a first argument

Comment: Thanks.  Just checked and we're on 5.3.1, so changing `Employee` to `__construct` didn't solve that problem.  You are correct about the `setEmployeeID` method - that does exist in the Employee class, but I didn't include it for brevity.   Could the private / public / protected issue affect the creation of the object?

Comment: Looking in the `setEmployeeID` methos, I notice it references other classes which I haven't included in my tests.  So I think that will solve the problem.  Thanks for your input - I will accept your answer.

Comment: re being on 5.3.1 -- wow. you really should upgrade that. the latest version is 5.3.19; there are a lot of fixes in between those versions, some of the important security patches.

Comment: also, the current version of phpUnit [requires PHP 5.3.3 or greater](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html), which may also be significant here.